# How to enable Platform.runlater within method

Tags: javafx

I am creating a Javafx chat app which also allows for file transfer. My issue is I open a FileOutputStream for the received file within the below method. I can see my listener.statusTransferring() updating the UI **only** if I enable Platform.runLater. I think I now need to enable the same on the  fos.write(b, 0, tmpTransferred) within the while loop but don't know how to do this. I have tried unsuccessfully wrapping the whole method within Platform runlater. Note: If I don't use platform runlater I don't get any errors however the UI does not update until the file transfer is complete eg listener.statusCompleted() is called;. The error I get now as a result of the fos being in Platform runlater. is below..  Line 185 is  fos.write(b, 0, tmpTransferred); The other listener calls appear to work fine. Just not   listener.statusTransferring(); or listener.transferUpdate(); which utilise the fos.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Also for your own sanity I am a self taught google programmer. Yep the worst kind I am sure. Thanks in advance.

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.thebowdens.net.FileReceiver.transfer(FileReceiver.java:185)
at net.thebowdens.net.DefaultMessageResponder.fileSend(DefaultMessageResponder.java:543)

```
 public boolean transfer() {
        
        listener.statusConnecting();

        received = false;
        cancel = false;

        try {
            if (sSock != null) {
                sock = sSock.accept();
               listener.statusTransferring();
                
                Platform.runLater(() ->{
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                is = sock.getInputStream();

                final byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                transferred = 0;
                percent = 0;
                int tmpTransferred = 0;
                int tmpPercent = 0;
                int transCounter = 0;
                bCounter.prepare();

                while (!cancel && (tmpTransferred = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(b, 0, tmpTransferred);
                    transferred += tmpTransferred;
                    percent = (int) ((transferred * 100) / size);
                    bCounter.addBytes(tmpTransferred);
                    transCounter++;

                    if (percent > tmpPercent || transCounter >= 250) {
                        transCounter = 0;
                        tmpPercent = percent;
                        listener.transferUpdate();
                    }
                }

                if (!cancel && transferred == size) {
                    received = true;
                   listener.statusCompleted();
                }

                else {
                    listener.statusFailed();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (final IOException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
            listener.statusFailed();
        }

        finally {
            stopReceiver();
            cleanupConnections();
        }

        return received;
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and do some research as to when you want to use Platform.runlater (starting with the api doc, going ahead with a tutorial on concurrency in javafx)

Comment: [Same comment as last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217866/restructure-method-to-enable-javafx-thread-visibility#comment113561839_64217866). And note that multi-threading can be complex, especially when you need to communicate between threads. If you aren't aware of what a _happens-before relationship_ is then I suggest doing some research regarding how concurrency works in Java. Understanding the fundamentals is important. Also, you may want to look into `javafx.concurrent.Task` as it provides an API to make communication with the FX thread easier.

Comment: That said, `runLater` schedules the `Runnable` to be executed on the _JavaFX Application Thread_ at some point in the future and returns immediately to the caller. So when the background thread tries to use `fos` it's still null because either (1) the `Runnable` has not been executed yet or (2) the `Runnable` has been executed but the background thread does not see the new, non-null value due to the missing aforementioned _happens-before_ relationship. Why are you initializing `fos` in a `runLater` call anyway? Ideally only code interacting with the UI should be wrapped in `runLater`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you should use [`Platform.runLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) **only** for updating the UI, everything else should be outside it otherwhise the UI will become unresponsive.

I suggest you to to refactor your code according to this.

Comment: Thanks. I have now gone and looked at each UI update using  if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
              listener.statusFailed();
               } else {
                Platform.runLater(() -> listener.statusFailed());
               } as an example. . I can see each is on the thread but the stage does not open properly(stays at bottom of page) I set the show method to showAndWait to see it comes up for the first part (Waiting) and it does but won't proceed as it is waiting.  I can see each function passing data correctly but the stage won't open. Concurrency issue somewhere?

Comment: First of all I'd get rid of the `if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {...} else {...}` using only `Platform.runLater(...)`.
This way every update to the UI will be queued in the JavaFX thread and the executed.
About your `stage` question I don't really understood the question; you may look at the `showAndWait` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) or integrate you initial question.

Answer (score -1):

Well after much discussion over the correct language and other issues I solved my problem of the UI updating. I had two issues. My choice selector and Filechooser methods were not on the Javafx application thread (hope this is the right terminology) so I had to do the following:

```
private  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    receiveRequest(tmpUser, fileRes, user, fileName, size, fileHash);
                } catch (IOException | ServerException | CommandException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

I then had to do the same within the Filechooser and file accept method for the transfer class UI to update

```
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
              @Override public void run() {
                if (fileRes.transfer()) {
                    ui.showSystemMessage("Successfully received " + fileName +
                            " from " + user + ", and saved as " + fileRes.getFile().getName());
                }
                else {
                    ui.showSystemMessage("Failed to receive " + fileName + " from " + user);
                    fileRes.cancel();
                }
            }
                 });
            }
```